# Console output filtering in xcode or appcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, console, output, appcode

Is it possible in **XCode or AppCode** to filter the output of the console like its implemented in IntelliJ? Or at least in *some* way?

Comment: As for AppCode, I haven't found any such plugin and if you find one, please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [GrepConsole plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125) in AppCode which enables coloring and filtering out messages based on regexps

Answer (score 3):

As for XCode, there is a plugin, called [MCLog](https://github.com/yuhua-chen/MCLog). Basically, it just adds regex-based filter to your console, no history or filter configurations, but it's still much better, than nothing.
You can install it using [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/) or directly from [GitHub repo](https://github.com/yuhua-chen/MCLog).

See, how it looks on original screenshots:
[image: Image taken from original GitHub repository]

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: MCLog doesn't work in XCode 8.0+

"Works in Xcode 5.0 through 7.3. Unfortunately, Apple no longer supports Xcode plug-ins as of Xcode 8.0."

Answer (score 2):

This feature is now available in Xcode itself for those still looking! It's in the bottom right corner of the console (separate from ⌘F in the console).  (Credit to Derek Yang for pointing this out to me!)

[image: Arrow pointing toward Xcode filter textfield in bottom right corner of console]